# Delete Text before and after a specific character in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, characters

i want to extract a string which is between two quotation marks, deleting everything before and after the quotation marks, including themselves. For example this:

> 6 6   "The Socratic Method"   Peter Medak John Mankiewicz 6.73[36]    50[36]  December 21, 2004
>
> 7 7   "Fidelity"  Bryan Spicer    Thomas L. Moran 6.91[37]    53[37]  December 28, 2004

should look like this afterwards:

> The Socratic Method
>
> Fidelity

is there a regular expression for NotePad++ to do so? Any other program which can do so would be ok, too. Thanks.

(And yes, those are Dr. House Episodes)^^

Comment: Do you mean [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Wordpad++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wordpadplusplus/)? Its unclear

Comment: Oh, sorry i meant to say Notepad++
I would also accept an Editor with features comparable to AdvancedRenamer or AntRenamer, where you can select to delete a specific number of characters after a specific position (for example: delete 5 characters after position 10)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go: Find and Replace (Ctrl + H)

Find: `.*"(.*)".*`

Replace: `\1`

You need to select "Regular expression" as Search Mode.

[image]

Comment: @Radoo simply superb